# Transforming sum-over-primes to sum-over-integers

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to develop a completer picture of the probability that a number randomly chosen in the region of $n$ has any given prime signature, at least to first approximation. The probability of a prime is close enough to $\frac{1}{\log{n}}$, which is well known; observing that the density of $k$th powers near $n$ is in the order of $\frac{1}{kn^{(k - 1)/k}}$, the probability of a signature $p^k$ then falls out nicely as $1/(n^{(k - 1)/k} \log{n})$.

Looking at the probability of a semiprime, I'm starting with "it's the sum of the (independent) probabilities for each prime p up to sqrt(n) that a) n is divisible by p (thus $1 / p$) and b) the result of division is prime (thus $1 / \log{n / p}$)":

$P = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{P}, i < \sqrt{n}}{ \frac{1}{i \log{n / i}} }$

Now I feel there should be a route from there, first to extend the sum over contiguous integers by including an ".. and i is prime" factor:

$P = \sum_{i = i_0}^{\sqrt{n}}{ \frac{1}{i \log{i} \log{n / i}} }$

.. and then to turn that contiguous sum into an integral:

$P = \int_{x_0}^{\sqrt{n}}{ \frac{dx}{x \log{x} \log{n / x}} }$

.. which I can then solve (via $e^u = x$) to evaluate:

$P = \frac{1}{\log{n}} [ \log{|u|} - \log{|\log{n} - u|} ]_{\log{n_0}}^{\log{\sqrt{n}}}$
$  = \frac{\log{\log{n / x_0}} - \log{\log{x_0}}}{\log{n}}$

.. but I don't know if those steps are justifiable, how the bounds
should be chosen if they are, or how to resolve the discrepancy with
Landau's result which (given the $p^k$ result above) implies I should get
something closer to either $P = \frac{\log{\log{n}}}{\log{n}}$ or $P = \frac{\log{\log{n}} - 1 / \sqrt{n}}{\log{n}}$ depending whether I expect this approximation to get close enough to notice the presence or absence of $p^2$. But trying to take $n_0$ close to 1 to make the first term approximate the right result sends the second term heading to $-\infty$.

So I guess my questions are:

- is the first type of transformation, from sum-over-primes to sum-over-integers, ever valid? Under what circumstances can it be so, and how should the bounds be determined?
- is the second type of transformation, from sum-over-integers to integral, ever valid? Under what circumstances can it be so, and how should the bounds be determined?

  - [update] in [approximation-of-a-sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246335) I found a useful explanation and a link to the [Euler–Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), which I think answers this part.
- have I messed up anything else?